# Single.php back button to parent category

Tags: php

I want to add a back button that goes to the parent category of the actual single post that the user is viewing. How can I do that?

```
<h2 class="link"><a href="#">Return</a></h2>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple categories?

Comment: there are a lot of categories but every single post belong to one and not to two or more

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Show_the_First_Category_Name_Only) and return the first result as in the example. Technically you could have several parent categories so you need to deal with this separately or expect that the first element of the array is always the right parent category.

Comment: get_the_category just get's the link of the same post...

Comment: Are you giving the $post->ID parameter to get_the_category
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code in `single.php` according to your theme style

```
$cats=get_the_category();
    foreach($cats as $cat){
/*check for category having parent or not except category id=1 which is wordpress default category (Uncategorized)*/
        if($cat->category_parent == 0 && $cat->term_id != 1){
            echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id ).'">Return</a></h2>';
        }
        break;
    }
```

Output HTML form this code:

```
<h2 class="link"><a href="(Link to first category which not have any parent category)">Return</a></h2>
```

**Important Link:**
[get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 class="link"><a href="<?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">Return</a></h2>
```

This should work!

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?